# Is There a Wired Mouse or Track Ball That Supports Gestures in OSX?

Tags: macos, mac, hardware-recommendation, gesture

I wanted to find out if there was a **wired** alternative to **Apple's Magic Mouse** or **Magic Trackpad** that also supports the gestures built into **OS-X Yosemite**, at the very least the ones supported by a Magic Mouse.

I realize that one alternative is just stick with the wireless Magic Mouse and go with a [Mobee Magic Charger for Apple Magic Mouse](http://www.mobeetechnology.com/the-magic-charger.html), but the reviews on the Apple Store have been mixed and I was wondering if anyone is using a wired device that gives them the ability to use OS-X gestures?

**Update**

Well searches of all the major sites, Apple, Amazon, B&H, MacLife, MacWorld, etc. has not yielded an answer on a wired mouse or trackball that support OS-X gestures. I figured I would bump this once to see if maybe I missed something, or if there is a designer out there who wants to go in on the deal to make one. ☺︎

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I found out that there is one option that kind of supports Apple's Magic Mouse and Magic Trackpad gestures.

The [Wacom Bamboo Pad](http://www.wacom.com/en-us/products/navigation/bamboo-pad-usb) allows you to control your Mac with touch gestures and comes in a wired, USB model.

If anyone finds another solution, please post it, because I was really looking for a wired mouse that can do this and would appreciate the input.

Thanks again,